# How to create Alias and Version for aws Lambda using CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

**Background + What I want to do:**

- I have 2 API stage : `prod` and `dev`  (When developing my app, I call to `dev` stage, when in production I will call to `prod` stage )
- Both stage will call to a same lambda function
- So I want to create 2 alias `dev` and `prod`
- Then `dev` alias will point to `$Latest` version (Which I currently will edit the code)
- Then `prod` alias will point to `version:5` (So when I editing the code, production app wont be affected)

**Here is the process:**

First I create a lambda function:

```
process_details_api_function = PythonFunction(
    self, 'ApiLambda',
    entry='lambda/ApiFunction',
    index='app.py',
    runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
    handler='ApiHandler',
    timeout=core.Duration.seconds(10),
    current_version_options=lambda_.VersionOptions(
          removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN)
    )
```

Then I make `alias` and `version` like this:

```
# This refer to the $Latest version
process_details_api_function_latest_version = process_details_api_function.latest_version

# This refer to version:5
process_details_api_function_prod_version = lambda_.Version.from_version_arn(
    self, "ProcessDetailApiProdVersion", process_details_api_function.function_arn + ":5")

# Create a `dev` alias and point to latest version 
process_details_api_function_dev_alias = lambda_.Alias(
    self, 'ProcessDetailApiFunctionDevAlias',
    alias_name="dev",
    version=process_details_api_function_latest_version
)

# create a `prod` alias and point it to prod version above 
process_details_api_function_prod_alias = lambda_.Alias(
    self, 'ProcessDetailApiFunctionProdAlias',
    alias_name="prod",
    version=process_details_api_function_prod_version
)
```

I create the API gateway

```
# Create a api 
api = apigateway.LambdaRestApi(
    self, "MyApi",
    handler=process_details_api_function)

latest_deployment = apigateway.Deployment(
    self, "LatestDeployment", api=api)

# Create a dev stage, Stage variable is `dev` 
dev_stage = apigateway.Stage(
     self, "DevStage", deployment=latest_deployment, stage_name="dev", variables={
        lambdaAlias": "dev"
})

api.deployment_stage = dev_stage
```

**Problem:**

The code above is successfully deploy. The lambda alias and version, api stage all are successfully created. But the problem is:

- When I edit the code of the lambda, no matter `dev` or `prod` also running the latest version code.

*For example:*

Code in Version:5 (Prod should hit this version )

```
def ApiHandler(event, context):
   print(event) 
    ## ... and any others codes here
```

Code in Latest (Dev should hit this version)

```
def ApiHandler(event, context):
   print(event) 
   print(event['stageVariables']['lambdaAlias'])
   ## ... and any others codes here
```

*Result I want:*

- Call to  `myAPIUrl/prod/endpoint` -> No `stageVariables` print
- Call to `myAPIUrl/dev/endpoint` -> Print the `stageVariables`

*Actual result*

But when I call my API no matter `prod` or `dev` stage, I also get the `stageVariables` print. No matter I call `myAPIUrl/prod/endpoint` or `myAPIUrl/dev/endpoint` I also get the stage variable print.

**Second attempt:**

So may be I create version and alias wrong, so I use this approach as well:

```
dev_version = my_function.latest_version
prod_version =my_function.add_version(
   "1", description="Production as 2/2/2021")

        
function_dev_alias = lambda_.Alias(
    self, 'DevAlias',
    alias_name="dev",
    version=dev_version
)

function_prod_alias = lambda_.Alias(
     self, 'ProdAlias',
     alias_name="prod",
    version=prod_version
)
```

But the result is still the same. No matter `/prod/endpoint` or `/dev/endpoint` both also call to code in `$Latest` version of the function.

I not sure what I doing wrong here. But both endpoint also point to same code.

Question:

- How to publish new version in aws CDK?
- How to point `alias` to respective `version`?
- How to keep updating the code in `dev` but the `prod` will not affected?
- What I doing wrong??

Somebody please point me in right direction. Thanks in advance.